# UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't work after resizing UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to programmatically move and expand the size of a `UIView` on tap and then, if the `UIView` is tapped again, animate it back to its original size and position.

I can get the `UIView` to expand and move on the first tap.  However, taps aren't registered at all after that initial animation.

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))

myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive  = true
myView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
myView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Below is my function that is called by handleTap to perform the initial animation on the first tap. It runs fine. I translate the position of myView and then change the frame size to make it bigger.

```
fileprivate func expandView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        let translate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 100, y: 50 )
        sender.view?.transform = translate
        sender.view?.backgroundColor = .green

    })  { (_) in

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            // change frame size of view to make it bigger
            sender.view?.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
        })
    }

}
```

I tried commenting out the animation that changes the frame size, leaving only the XY translation. That also doesn't allow handleTap to fire again when tapping myView.

Comment: Don't set `frame` when you have set the `transform` to something else. Decide what you want to change - `transform` or `frame`? You should stick to changing one of them.

Comment: The issue is still the same however even if I remove the frame change animation. handleTap doesn't get called again after the translate transformation.

Comment: Because you haven't written the code to change the frame back!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.  When the frame change is stripped out, handleTap still doesn't get called.